# Htaccess redirect seems not working with php file extension to seo friendly (no extension) url

Tags: php, .htaccess

One of my website's old URL structures is like this:

```
    https://example.com/login.php
    or, 
    https://example.com/login.php?redirect=https://example.com
    or,
    https://example.com/register.php
```

after rebuilding the URLs, the URLs look like this:

```
    https://example.com/login
    or, 
    https://example.com/login?redirect=https://example.com
    or,
    https://example.com/register
```

Now when the user/visitor uses the old URL `https://example.com/login.php`, I want to redirect to the `https://example.com/login` page. How can I do it?

FYI, currently, my `.htaccess` file has the following content:

```
AddDefaultCharset UTF-8

ErrorDocument 404 /error-404/

##
Options +FollowSymlinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

## Allow a few SEO Files direct access.
RewriteRule ^robots.txt?$ robots.txt [L]
RewriteRule ^ads.txt?$ ads.txt [L]
RewriteRule ^sellers.json?$ sellers.json [L]


## Avoid rewriting rules for the admin section
RewriteRule ^(admin|resources)($|/) - [L]

## Set Ajax Request File
RewriteRule ^kahuk-ajax.php?$ kahuk-ajax.php? [L,QSA]

## Set controller with id
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([0-9]+)/?$ index.php?con=$1&id=$2 [L,QSA]

## Set controller with slug
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ index.php?con=$1&slug=$2 [L,QSA]

## For paging
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/page/([0-9]+)/?$ index.php?con=$1&page=$2 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/page/([0-9]+)/?$ index.php?con=$1&slug=$2&page=$3 [L,QSA]

## Set controller for only one parameter
RewriteRule ^page/([^/]+)/?$ index.php?con=page&slug=$1 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ index.php?con=$1 [L,QSA]

## Set home page
RewriteRule ^/?$ index.php?con=home [L]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can insert this rule just below `RewriteBase /` line to remove `.php` extension:

```bash
# To externally redirect /afile.php to /afile
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+(.+?)\.php[\s?] [NC]
RewriteRule !^admin/ /%1 [R=301,NE,L,NC]
```

Comment: Seems it is good, but it is also overriding extension from this URL `https://example.com/admin/admin_attention?hello=world`. I don't want to redirect when the file is in `/admin`.

Comment: ok try my updated rule now

Comment: No luck. Still redirecting from `https://example.com/admin/admin_attention.php?hello=world` to `https://example.com/admin/admin_attention?hello=world`.

Comment: FYI, it does not redirect the `https://example.com/admin/admin_links.php` to `https://example.com/admin/admin_links`. which is good.

Comment: That just means you have old browser cache for `https://example.com/admin/admin_attention.php`. Just test in a new browser or completely clear browser cache

Comment: my bad, I guess your solution is working. I need to test it more after clearing the cache. Anyway, THANK YOU very much.

Comment: Sure, I'll mark it answer after testing it some more time. I'll let you know the update. By the way, can you tell me what to do if I just want to redirect only the `/login.php` to `/login`  and `/register.php` to `/login`, not other files.

Comment: In that case use first line: `RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+(login|register)\.php[\s?] [NC]`